# I have a class object as a member of another class, how do I initialize as a safe empty state?

Tags: c++, constructor

I have 2 classes, ISBN, Order. I have an ISBN object as a data member of my Order class and I am having issues with the Order constructor to place the ISBN object in a safe empty state.

My Order.h

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class ISBN;

class Order {

int ordered;
int delivered;
ISBN * book;
bool empty;

public:

Order();
Order(const ISBN & isbn);


};
```

My ISBN.h

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class ISBNPrefix;

class ISBN {

char isbnNum[13];
char area[6];
char publisher[8];
char title[7];
char checkDigit[1];
bool emptycheck;
bool registered;

public:

ISBN();
ISBN(const char * str, const ISBNPrefix& list);
}
```

In my Order constructor I tried this code:

```
Order::Order() {

ordered = 0;
delivered = 0;
empty = true;

*book->ISBN();

/*
(*book).isbnNum[0] = '\0';
book.area[0] = '\0';
book.publisher[0] = '\0';
book.title[0] = '\0';
book.checkDigit[0] = '\0';
book.emptycheck = true;
book.registered = false; */
}
```

And variations of it, but I get errors like: "type name is not allowed" "expression must have pointer type" etc...Anyone know what my issue is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You almost certainly don't want a pointer here, just an `ISBN` object as a data member:

```
ISBN book;
```

This will automatically be initialised using its default constructor; you don't need to do anything. If you want to initialise it using the other constructor (with arguments), then you'll need to do that in the initialiser list:

```
Order::Order() : book(some_string, some_list)
{
    // body of constructor
}
```

Comment: Oh ok didn't think about it being automatically being intialized. What about my constructor and copy constructor for the Order class? What do I do with the book object since I have to initialize the other data members?

Comment: Also I get another error if I just declare it as "ISBN book" the error is : "field 'book' has incomplete type

Comment: @user2140629: If it's a data member, then the implicit copy constructor and assignment operator will copy it to the new object. Again, you don't have to do anything.

Comment: @user2140629: For it to be a member, then the definition must be available. You'll need to `#include "ISBN.h"`, rather than just declaring `class ISBN;`.

Comment: Ok nvm got it to work. I just changed the place of #include "ISBN.h" to my Order.h file and it worked thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You are having problems because you have declared `book` as an `ISBN*`. Therefore your posted line `*book->ISBN();` is trying to dereference a null and then call the blank constructor.

If you want to manually allocate `book`, then you should then use this pattern:

```
Order::Order() {

    ordered = 0;
    delivered = 0;
    empty = true;
    book = new ISBN();
}
```

Note this will require `Order`'s destructor to call delete on its `book` member.

You can automatically allocate and delete `book` as an `ISBN` by making it a class member, and not a pointer. For that, use this declaration:

```
class Order {

    ISBN book;
    ... // your other members
}
```

This will automatically allocate and automatically deallocate an `ISBN` object member whenever class `Order` is instatiated and destroyed respectively. No additional steps necessary.